# How to find Root node in a Hierarchical Data from a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the Root node that need to shown in all the Sub nodes. I tried in Recursive CTE but its not working as required.

Table Struct:

Node Parent_Node
A,   NULL
B,   A
C,   B
D,   C
E,   NULL
F,   E
G,   F

Output

Node Root Node 
A,NULL
B,   A
C,   A
D,   A
E,NULL
F,   E
G,   E

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? It can be useful for debugging. @Thiyagu

Comment: One trick to try in addition to the "normal" rCTE approach - tack on a column that is the root id. That is, you'd typically have `select child.id, parent.id...` in the recursive part. Also add `parent.rootid` as a column which will trickle down from root to all child nodes in the tree.

Comment: @ Ben Thul please can you offer a hint because i m trying to solve this and i m stuck.Please